# Where is the Gare du Nord taxi station?

Tags: paris, taxis, eurostar, train-stations

I will be arriving at Gare du Nord train station from London. I will need a taxi. I have read, that there are clear signs indicating where taxis are located but I did not read exactly what's the street of taxi rank.

1. Can some one tell me the exact street outside gare du nord where taxi's are queued up for pickup ?
2. Can I get a taxi without prebooking it or do I need to prebook it ?
3. I intend to stay in a hotel near Gare du nord. If I want a ride back to airport for my flight to NYC, can I queue up in the same taxi queue of Gare du nord, or is the taxi queue exclusively reserved for passengers who arrived from train ?

Comment: Any reason not to use Uber instead?

Comment: Gard Du Nord is a very large international station. I very much doubt you will have trouble finding the taxi rank; it will be clearly signposted. Even if you do, you will easily find someone who speaks enough English to point you at it. You will not need to prebook a taxi.

Comment: @JonathanReez There are many one could suggest.

Comment: @javadeveloper
If you're at Gare du Nord, I think you'll be just as quick (and much cheaper) to ride the RER out to CDG, rather than pay ~€100 for a Taxi.

Comment: @JonathanReez, some reasons: Not being familiar with the system, not having a smart phone so no app, not having date (or only at very high costs)  and lastly, trusting the liveried taxis over the unknown of Uber. And those are just my reasons, maybe he has more or others.

Comment: @Willeke I think the *modus operandi* on Travel.SE is to try and solve the task at hand, rather than strictly going with the solution offered by the author, as it might sometimes be inferior. From what I personally know about Paris cabs, I would never go near one if I could use Uber instead.

Comment: @JonathanReez Based on previous posts, the asker will not have a smartphone with them.

Comment: "Trusting the liveried taxis"... You obviously have no experience with taxis in Paris. Even though most are fine and some are excellent, way too many are really, really bad. From those who will be listening to the football match at full blast, those who smoke in their taxi, those who are yapping on the phone, those who will take you for a ride, those who arrive with 30 euros on the meter when you ring one up, and the most frequent one, those who won't take you because "you're not going far enough"...

Comment: Also, be aware that it's not infrequent that taxis don't actually know any street in Paris. If you don't have a full address they can enter into their GPS, they won't be able to take you anywhere. Unless it's an airport. They all know how to get to airports. Oh, did I mention that most think they only job in life is driving you to the airport? Preferably taking a detour, as they only know a single road to get there.

Comment: If you have little luggage, consider taking the metro and/or RER. gare du nord is very well connected, and you'll be anywhere in Paris way faster and cheaper than using a taxi. traffic in paris is often horrible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read French / have google translate handy, you can [find the information you seek on the SNCF Stations page for Gare du Nord here](http://www.gares-sncf.com/fr/gare/frpno/paris-gare-du-nord/transports-horaires/transports-individuels/taxis#service-280). It even includes a photo! The key bit is:

> Localisation
>
> Station de taxis sur le parvis de la gare -> Cour des taxis Rue de Dunkerque

The taxi rank is located near the Eurostar platforms, at the South West corner of the station, by Rue de Dunkerque.

As you come off a Eurostar, turn right when you exit the platform into the main area, and walk out of the exit straight ahead of you. The taxi rank is right there. You may have to queue, especially if you're towards the back of a Eurostar, but you don't normally need to book

Otherwise, outside of the very busiest times, you'll find taxis outside the main station entrance on Place Napoléon III / Rue de Dunkerque.

Comment: Be aware that the queue can indeed take quite a while, especially at busy times, if it's raining, or if there any sort of strike. If you get at the end of the queue just after an Eurostar and a Thalys just arrived, it can easily take an hour.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really miss the queue, you'll see them easily while getting outside.

Then yes you can pick a taxi in the street without queuing if he is available (green light on).

The taxi queue isn't reserved to train customers, anybody can get into it.

Comment: do i need to 'prebook' the taxi?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper, no, not in the regular queue. You can prebook a taxi to avoid the queue, though. In that case you'll probably not use the taxi rank/queue (they'll either meet you at the end of the platform with a sign bearing your name, or they'll give you instructions on where they are parked).

Comment: Also prebooking a taxi **may** get you a better taxi & driver, especially if you book with a reputable company (like G7).

Comment: @jcaron doubtful. all taxis are pretty much affiliated with G7/Taxi Bleu call center.

Comment: G7 and Taxis Bleus are two different companies, and from experience, G7 is often far better than Taxis Bleus. Ideally you want a "classe affaires" taxi from G7, but I'm not sure you can be sure to get one unless you're a subscriber. There are a few others companies which are even worse than Taxis Bleus, and a **lot** of taxis which are not affiliated with either (17K taxis in Paris, 7.7K with G7, 3K with Taxis Bleus, 1.5K with Alpha Taxis, that leaves quite a few others).

Answer (score -1):

I've found the taxis pretty reliable, but they can get expensive, and as one comment indicated you can get the odd bad one.

Why not consider using the Paris Metro.  It is quick, reliable and goes most places you would want to go as a visitor.  It is easy and quite cheap to use, and few locations are further than a couple of hundred metres from the nearest Metro station.